# Disable certain ListViewItem depending on custom property UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have a `ListView` that contains several types of custom `UserControls`.

The project requires that some of them must be non-clickable, so I would like to disable them, but **JUST THEM**.

Those items will be enabled/disabled depending on the value of a custom property.

I've tried to set the `ListViewItem.IsEnabled` property to `false`, but it ain't worked, and the other solutions I've found around make no sense to me...

I let a sample of the code:

XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="homeLW"
                  Margin="0,5,0,0"
                  ItemClick="homeLW_ItemClick"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source}">
```

Where `Source` is a `ObservableCollection<UserControl>`.

The problem is that I can't get the items of the `ListView` as `ListViewItems`, but as the `UserControl` type:. When executing this:

```
foreach(ListViewItem lwI in homeLW.Items)
            {
                //CODE
            }
```

I get:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   UserControl.Type to type Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem.

Anyone know how could I make it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please post relevant xaml and code behind code

Comment: @LovetoCode it's a generic question... I think the code it's irrelevant, but I can post the code if you want me to

Comment: Actually ListViewItem.IsEnabled=false does work. You said it doesnt work. So i wanted to check the code

Comment: Have you tried setting IsHitTestVisible=false?

Comment: You have to edit ItemContainner style,there you set IsEnabled property of LIstViewItem. Are you trying to use binding to set IsEnabled?

Comment: Use homeLW.ContainerFromItem(lwI) to get LIstVIewItem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach(var lwI in homeLW.Items)
            {
              ListViewItem item =(ListViewItem)homeLW.ContainerFromItem(lwI);
              item.IsEnabled = false;
            }
```

When on load all `ListViewItems` wont be loaded because of Virtualization. So you get Null when try to get container from item. Workaround would be switching off the virtualization. But it will have performance effects. Since you confirmed that it wont be having more than 20 items,I ll go ahead and add the code

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel> 
    <ItemsPanelTemplate> 
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" /> 
    </ItemsPanelTemplate> 
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Comment: On which line?? item is null?

Comment: Can you tell me what is the type of item. I guess cast to ListViewItem gives null.

Comment: It's a custom `UserControl`

Comment: Use Source(which you used in  ItemsSource="{Binding Source}")  instead of homeLW.Items

Comment: Still gettin' Null :(

Comment: Its unable to guess what is wrong with minimal code. Usually it should give ListViewItem. I have no idea why ContainerFromItem gives usercontrol. Check the parent of usercontrol

Comment: I can share the whole code, but i've posted the relevant one. I don't know what else to share

Comment: I'm guessing itemtemplate is usercontrol. I checked with usercontrol as itemtemplate. Its giving me proper ListViewItem

Comment: Nope, ContainerFromItem gives Null, not UserControl. If I access the ListViewItem through homeLW.Items, I get UserControl. I can't use a template since I'm using several types of UserControls that are pretty different from each other.

Comment: homeLW.Items is data collection. You cant cast it directly to ListVIewItem. thats why i declared `var lwI`. are you doing the same?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same.

Comment: Sorry I havent read your question properly. Now i got your items are Observable collection of UserControl.

Comment: When you access homeLW.Items  you get UserControl. Thats correct. But when you pass it to ContainerFromItem  you get ListVIewItem. I'm getting it. If you still dont get. Give me a link to your code. I'll check

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Here you have a link to some code: https://gist.github.com/evafp90/67add4a9140c521d69ac3799a91d5e58. I think I've put everything relevant. You'll that just a couple of UserControls are there, but those are which I want to disable.

Comment: where are you making items disabled? In homeLW_ItemClick?

Comment: No, after filling the ItemsSource. The method is called `DisableItems'

Comment: Can i run the project with this minimal code? I guess not

Comment: nope, you wont' be able :( and unfortunately there are hundred of files that I can't share

Comment: I tried it before... in fact, it's the solution you gave me above :( it's really really weird, isn't it?

Comment: No... it always retrieve NullReferenceExceptions. Both using homeLW.Items and Source

Comment: Yes. It's weird. It always should give. Try calling Disable method  after loading ListView. In ListView loaded event

Comment: Have added `Loaded` event and put the method `DisableItems()` in it, but now the loop is not run, as if `homeLW.Items` or `Source` were empty :S

Comment: I have tested again, now it runs the code inside the loop and still retrieves null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111717/discussion-between-lovetocode-and-eva-fp).

Answer (score 0):

To add onto LoveToCode's answer, if you want to disable the selected items on load and not turn off Virtualization, you'll need to fire the code when the UIElement is loaded. Otherwise, you'll get a System.NullReferenceException. The reason for this is because the Framework Element hasn't been loaded to reference the ListView Container.

```
homeLW.Loaded += DisableSelectedItemsOnLoad()

private void DisableSelectedItemsOnLoad()
{
    foreach(var lwI in homeLW.Items)
    {
        ListViewItem item =(ListViewItem)homeLW.ContainerFromItem(lwI);
        item.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: the virtualization part is correct, but this solution does not have any effect.