# Make specific ListView item not clickable in Universal Windows Platform

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, microsoft-metro, uwp

I am using a `ListView` element in my XAML:

```
                <ListView
                x:Name="myList"
                IsItemClickEnabled="true"
                ItemClick="onDrawerItemClick"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Grid
                            Width="260">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition
                                    Width="44" />
                                <ColumnDefinition
                                    Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image
                                x:Name="image"
                                Source="{Binding myIcon}"
                                Grid.Column="0" />

                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding myTxt}"
                                Grid.Column="1" />

                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

and I populate it using Bind property like so:

```
List<MyObj> listData = a list with title + image uri;
myList.ItemsSource = listData;
```

I need to disable click only for some items depending on some value from `MyObj` in my list but the others to have it. In Android we use adapter for that, how should I handle it here?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132267/disable-certain-listviewitem-depending-on-custom-property-uwp/37133619#37133619

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you should create a new `bool` property called `Disabled` inside your `MyObj` object.

Then, subscribe to `myList`'s `ContainerContentChanging` event where you have access to the `ListViewItem` and its corresponding `Item`, which in this case is your `MyObj`. So, if `MyObj.Disabled` is `true`, make that `ListViewItem` non-clickable.

```
private void myList_ContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    var listViewItem = args.ItemContainer;

    if (listViewItem != null)
    {
        var model = (MyObj)args.Item;

        if (model.Disabled)
        {
            listViewItem.IsHitTestVisible = false;

            // OR
            //listViewItem.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you might want to use `listViewItem.IsEnabled = false` if you want that item to appear dimmed. This is because the default `ListViewItem`style has a *Disabled* state that reduces its `Opacity`; while setting `listViewItem.IsHitTestVisible = false` won't change its appearance in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The listView is a strange control as it does not have any mechanism to disable selection.

So what I suggest you do is rather handle the event that notifies the framework that an item has been selected by attaching an event handler to ItemSelectionChanged and in there perform a deselect on the item:

```
yourListView.ItemSelectionChanged += yourListView_ItemSelectionChanged;

private void yourListView_ItemSelectionChanged(
    object sender,
    ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.IsSelected)
      e.Item.Selected = false;
}
```

Please let me know if my answer helps :)